# Expo react native app different status bar behavior in apk vs expo go

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using react native paper Appbar for header

```
<View>
    <Appbar.Header style={{backgroundColor:'#FFC312'}}>
      <Appbar.Action icon="cart"/>
      <Appbar.Content title="Cart " />
    </Appbar.Header>
...
```

This Cart component is inside a tab navigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
<Tab.Screen
     name="Cart"
     component={Cart}
     options={{
           tabBarLabel: 'Cart',
           tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <Icon name="shopping-cart" color={color} size={20} />
              ),
           unmountOnBlur: false,
     }}
/>
...
```

This navigator is rendered in App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
   <TabNavigation />
  );
}
```

When i test this in expo go, status bar looks like this -

[image]

When i export apk using expo and test in my android phone, status bar is not covered with yellow color, its white and there is a gap between status bar and the cart text

[image]

I would appreciate and answer with reason and a little explanation, and solution of course !

Thanks for your help.